# How to wrap regex pattern in <b> tag using jquery

Tags: jquery, html, regex

I have an editable div tag what i want is when the user start typing if he types a hash-tag followed by some characters the whole thing should be wraped inside a  tag example

say user starts typing so we got the following in the div-tag

I want this

```
<div>Hello world! #FirstDay #Nice #DoingOk #Number20</div>
```

To be like this

```
<div>
    Hello world! <b>#FirstDay</b> <b>#Nice</b> <b>#DoingOk</b> <b>#Number20</b>
</div>
```

For every occurrence if the user starts typing hash-tag something it should wrap it in a  tag till the break which is the space.

Comment: And here comes that post telling you not to parse HTML with regex...

Comment: Did you try something on your own? It isn't difficult

Comment: Guys if i succeed doing it on my own why would i ask &  if it was so easy then why not help me out forgive me am not that smart but am really tired of comments like that.

Comment: You should show the community what you have tried so far and you will get help definitively. And really quick! Just asking for homework is very likely to retrieving some blames, so don't mind about that.

Comment: What programming language? serverside or clientside? What is your current code to solve the problem?

Comment: @BeyondProgramming About my comment: I am on your side really. I strongly feel there are some times a regex is useful in HTML context (like yours). But some tend to whenever they see the keywords "regex" and "html" together, post a link to a famous answer that says regex shouldn't be used to so. They don't even bother reading the questions.

Comment: @Axel Amthor it's not my homework it's my graduation project & yes i tried doing it my self but failed & my mind just blocked so i thought of asking for assistance, am not forcing any one to help me so in return am just asking the people who comment if you got the intention to help me then am grateful but if you don't want to help why criticize & mock?, I know i wouldn't do that so i hate people doing that to me and that's all.

Comment: I didn't criticize you, I tried to explain why you're getting blames on the way you're asking for help. But some are hopeless ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what i wanted to achieve for any one facing the same problem & want to learn.

CSS:

```
.TextArea {
    width: 300px;
    height: 30px;
    border: 1px solid rgb(204, 204, 204);
    margin: 0px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    Padding: 5px;
    color: #444;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
    resize: none;
    outline: 0;
    z-index: 2;
    background-color: transparent;
    position: relative;
    font-family: Arial,Helvetica,Verdana,sans-serif;
    line-height: 1.28;
    font-size: 12px;
}
.DivTag {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    border: 1px solid rgb(204, 204, 204);
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: white;
    zoom: 1;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 5px;
    width: 300px;
    height: 30px;
    line-height: 1.28;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: pre-wrap;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    font-family: Arial,Helvetica,Verdana,sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
}

.boldTag {
    background: #d8dfea;
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, center top, center bottom, from(#dce6f8), to(#bdcff1));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#dce6f8, #bdcff1);
    -webkit-border-radius: 2px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px #a3bcea;
    font-weight: normal;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class = "DivTag"></div>
<textarea class="TextArea"></textarea>
```

Jquery:

```
$('.TextArea').keyup(function () {
        var txt = $('.TextArea').val();
        $(".DivTag").text(txt);
        var DivTag = $(".DivTag").text();
        var $div = $(".DivTag");
        $div.html(DivTag.replace(/\s(\#[a-zA-Z]\w*)/g, " <b class='boldTag'>$1</b>"));
        text = $(".DivTag").text();
        text = text.replace(/\s+/g, " ");
        text = text.trim();
});
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/7cGCZ/3/

Answer (score 3):

The simplest method:

```
$('div').replace( /\#(\S+)/g, "<b>$1</b>" )
```

Here is a working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7cGCZ/2

Comment: You got me by matter of seconds ;p

Comment: I hope, in the vineyard of Your Excellency that you can tell me how to make sure there is a space before the hash-tag

Comment: @BeyondProgramming Use `\s\#`. `\s` => space; `\S` => Anything not-space.

Comment: Again thanks sir i hope i have not bothered you with my silly questions & sorry for wasting your time.

Comment: forgot the # symbol in your $1

Answer (score 2):

Try `.replace()`, like:

```
var sid = $('#someDIV').html();
$('#someDIV').html(sid.replace(/(#\S+)\s/g, '<b>$1</b> '));
```